# Получение данных по связям Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Решаю такую задачу. 
Есть Разделы (Partition), рубрики (Rubric), записи (Post).

Нужно получить 10 записей в каждой рубрике каждого раздела. Делал с помощью связей примерно так:

```
$partitions = Partition::with(['rubrics', 'posts'])->get();
```

В таком случае получаю всего 10 записей, а не 10 записей в каждой рубрике.

Переделал так:

```
$partitions = Partition::with(['rubrics'])->get();
foreach($partitions as $partition) {
    foreach($partition->rubrics as $rubric) {
        $rubric->load(['posts']);
    }
}
```

Так работает как надо, но запросов получается слишком много, а рубрик с ростом проекта будет все больше и больше.

Возможно ли решить данную задачу с помощью связей Eloquent? Если да, то как? А если нет - в какую сторону тогда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял вы хотите через реляцию "жадной" выгрузкой забрать данные. Вложенные реляции просто нужно указать через точку:

```
$partitions = Partition::with('rubrics.posts')->get();
```

А если по 10 записей, попробуйте следующее:

```
$partitions = Partition::with(['rubrics.posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->limit(10);
}])->get();
```

P.S. В одном примере реляция `rubrics`, в другом `rubric`, не понятно какие настоящие из вашего вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за поправку, текст вопроса поправил, отношение 'rubrics'. Замыкание пробовал использовать. Это не совсем подходит т.к. в таком случае получается примерно такой запрос:

select * from `posts` where `posts`.`parent_id` in (13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 14, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 28, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31) limit 10

По такому запросу я получаю 10 записей из всех рубрик текущего раздела. Мне же нужно получить 10 записей из каждой рубрики каждого раздела.